# ¿Se puede utilizar Python en HTML?

Tags: html, python

¡Hola!

Oigan, quería saber si se puede utilizar Python en HTML; algo así como lo que hace JavaScript.
Si sí se puede, agradecería que me dijeran cómo.

Perdón si mi pregunta los incomoda; estoy aprendiendo los dos lenguajes desde hace unos 3 meses, así que no sé demasiado.

Gracias.

Comment: Python se ejecuta en el servidor y no cuenta con compatibilidad con HTML

Comment: Se puede usar Python para generar HTML desde el servidor y servirlo al navegador, ya sea directamente (similar como PHP), o con frameworks como Django. Para ejecutar comandos en el frontend, Javascript es tu lenguaje.

Comment: La respuesta corta es: NO. Aunque supongo que lo habrás intentado y te darías cuenta por ti mismo. Respuesta larga: basta escribir código Python en un tag de tipo <script>, por ejemplo. Y aunque coloques un atributo `type="application/x-python-code"`, el bloque será tratado como bloque de datos y no será procesado (compilado y ejecutado) por el navegador. Los navegadores (aún) no disponen de un intérprete Python propio, por lo cual, no puedes ejecutar código de Python directamente en el navegador, tal como planteas en tu pregunta. Saludos

Comment: Los navegadores modernos pueden ejecutar webassembly (wasm) para el que existe un intérprete python: https://pyodide.org

Comment: Existe algo llamado pyscript https://pyscript.net/, revísalo a ver si te funciona.

Answer (score 1):

La respuesta corta es que no. Oficialmente los navegadores web soportan únicamente JavaScript como lenguaje para el elemento `<script>`.

No obstante hay experimentos muy recientes para tratar de hacer justamente lo que pides, es decir, algo como lo siguiente:

```
<script type="text/python">
from browser import document

document.attach("¡Hola!")
</script>
```

¡Sí! ¡Es Python dentro de un elemento `<script>`! Para que funcione necesitas usar [Brython](https://brython.info/index.html), que básicamente es un intérprete Python en javascript. Basta añadir en tu cabecera HTML lo siguiente:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script type="text/javascript"
        src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/brython@3.9.0/brython.min.js">
    </script>
</head>
```

Pero no es python del todo "estándar", como ves, pues necesita interactuar con el DOM del navegador por lo que necesitarás conocimientos de qué es eso, y de cómo han implementado los desarrolladores de Brython una API para acceder a ese DOM (y a otras facilidades de javascript) desde Python.

Personalmente no creo que sea buena idea si estás empezando con python, pues puede confundirte mucho y apartarte de lo que es python "en realidad". Pero es una idea interesante que habrá que ver a dónde lleva. De momento hay una compañía ([Anvil](https://anvil.works/)) que lo ha usado para crear una plataforma de desarrollo de aplicaciones web basadas completamente en Python, tanto en el back como en el front.

Answer (score 0):

Usando flask, que usa la libreria Jinja, esta última permite introducir código Python dentro de una pagina html. Tiene alguna diferencia de síntaxis, como poner el código entre doble corchetes, o corchete y porcentaje como por ejemplo:

```
{% if variable %}
{{ variable_del codigo }}
{% endif %}
```

Puede que no sea tan directo, pero igual te permite hacer lo que pretendes.

Comment: Creo que no es esto lo que pretende, sino poder incluir Python _que se ejecute en el navegador_ (no en el servidor), como si fuera javascript.